# how to send a razor view page to ajax json

Tags: json, razor

my Razor view page name is LazyLoad.cshtml.

i'm trying to pass it into ajax json as like below

```
function AddArticleRecord() {
            alert("Event Fired");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:"/FeaturedArticleLazyLoad",
                async: true,
                data: 'searchstring=1',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
},
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
```

but it showing error as "**404 Not Found**"

please help me  how to solve this error?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Typically `url` should be in form `/controller/action`. Or `/controller` with default action defined in routing. Do you have controller `FeaturedArticleLazyLoad`?

Answer (score 0):

Views are not how you do paths in MVC. The whole routing mechanism is very, very flexible, but regardless of how you configure the routes the end up at a controller action, which can then return the view you want.

So, assuming you haven't changed the routing it defaults to controller\action with the caveat that you have a default index available to you as well. So the path you go to via ajax call needs to line up with this Pattern. You can try directly browsing to the requested page to see all of that in action.